# HTML5 animations creating a dashed border that smoothly moves inward on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a drag and drop module - and need to have it so that when the dragging process occurs - the dashed line around the outside moves in and the box goes a particular color. I don't want the look of the dashed line to change though. There is the option of maybe having the dashed line animate move around the edge of the box

.

- for now its ensuring the contents doesn't jump - to make it absolutely positioned so its disconnected from the border morphing?
- how to css3 animate the border moving in/out smoothly?

https://jsfiddle.net/L47xrsnt/4/

html

```
<div class="drag-drop">
  <div class="drag-drop-border">
    <div class="contents">
      xx
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.drag-drop {

  .drag-drop-border {
    border: 2px dashed pink;
  }

  &:hover {
    padding: 15px;
    background: gold;
  }

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: here is the solution --- https://jsfiddle.net/L47xrsnt/20/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like below:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 2px dashed pink;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover::before {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L47xrsnt/20/ -- thanks - that's working well

Answer (score 0):

To make the border transition smoother, you can add following CSS code in your :

```
{
    transition: 0.5s padding ease-in-out;
}
```

You can add other parameters in transaction as per your requirement.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L47xrsnt/15/ - I've added it in - but trying to keep it the same height as it was originally -- not sure